# Anchors with dynamic HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have a website on which comments are loaded via AJAX. I would like to create some links that point to some specific comments.

I have tried both:

```
<a name="comment-123"></a>
<a id="comment-123"></a>
```

It only works when the link #comment-123 is called from the same page. If called from another page, the page displays at its top.

Maybe its because the content is loaded after with javascript?

Comment: You would have to goto that link after your comments loads or else it wouldn't exist so the page won't go anywhere

Comment: If the anchor doesn't exist, you're right, the page won't be able to go to it on load. Are you providing the full URL on the links on other pages?